# Would these regexes match different strings?

Tags: regex

```
([^/]+)/(thumb)\.(jpg)$
([^/]+/)?(thumb)\.(jpg)$
```

I know the `?` means zero or one times. Does having the `/` before `thumb` mean that it occurs once?

Comment: Yes they may match different inputs. `/` is just a literal slash

Comment: regexr.com says the second one is broken.  Error: unescaped forward slash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes they match different things.

For example, this one:

```
([^/]+/)?(thumb)\.(jpg)$
```

matches the string: `thumb.jpg`

The `?` makes the whole subexpression optional.

The other one does not.

```
([^/]+)/(thumb)\.(jpg)$
       ^
```

As you can see, the `/` is static, so it must be present.

Also, there must be at least one not `/` characters before it. That's what the `+` means.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the first expression requires the `/` in the string, and at least 1 character before it different than `/`.

In the second expression it is not required. For example, `thumb.jpg` would match the second but not the first.

Finally, every string matched by the first expression will also match the second.